# Confused on Github instructions on Udacity for Sunshine App

Tags: git, github

How do I do these steps on windows and what tool should I use. I've downloaded and installed Git.

1. Open a terminal and navigate to the folder you want to have your code in. Your AndroidStudioProjects folder, which can usually be found in your user directory, is a fine location.
2. Clone the repository into the folder using the following command:
   git clone https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2.git
3. Go into the Sunshine-Version-2 directory you just cloned.
   Checkout the first branch using the following command:
   git checkout 1.01_hello_world

Comment: Use your terminal. Press the “Win + R” key to open RUN dialog box. Type cmd, and click/tap on OK

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go through GitHub's included basic 10 minute tutorial

[GitHub CodeSchool command line interactive tutorial](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)

Also, to navigate to a specific folder it's something like this

```
cd /f/folder/somefolder
```

Also, this page is going to help you understand about how to clone.

[Creating Project Pages from the Command Line](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: strongly suggest not hiding the URL's with "Here" text so that they are visible. Additionally link only answers are frowned upon. If those links break your answer becomes useless. Suggest either adding some additional  information here or considering to provide these as a comment.  That said I agree, they need to go through githubs basic tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

If you are uncomfortable working from the command prompt you could look into installing a [GUI for git](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis). Otherwise use `cd` to navigate to your chosen folder and run the other commands from there.